# How do I redirect from a childpath to another path that is a level above said path in Angular 4?

Tags: routes, angular4-router

I am trying to redirect to another path that is not in the 'children' array for a given path but is a level above it. I've tried using '../' as I see it can be used in other places such as routerLink, but it doesn't seem to work the way I want it to. Please see image attached [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80sf2.png). Thanks for any help or alternatives.